# passing --read-only flag to azure webapp container

Tags: azure-web-app-service, containers

I am trying to harden the container which is running inside the azure app service.
How can i pass flags like "--read-only" to the docker command from azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, to pass the flag `--read-only` to the docker command from **Azure portal** is not possible. You can do the same using the **docker CLI** command.

```
 docker run --read-only -v /icanwrite busybox touch /icanwrite/here
```

You can refer to [Mount volume (-v, --read-only)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only) and [Deploying Docker containers on Azure](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/)